# Microsoft Office / Word: How to find text between /* and */?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find

I have a Microsoft Word (Office 365) document with some java code in it:

```
Java code...

/* Comment
    0. dog
    1. cat
    2. cow
*/

Java code...
```

What I would like to do  is set the font color of all comments to gray. I could do this with Find and Replace, but I cannot figure out what "regex" to use to find the comments.

I can use `/\*` to find /*, `\*/` to find */, and `Com*cow` in the example above to find all the text between Com and cow.

Based on this I would guess that `/\**\*/` should find all the text between /* and */ , but it does not. What is the correct keyword to use?

(I know that as a workaround I could first replace all occurrences of /* with TAG1 and all occurrences of */ with TAG2, then use `TAG1*TAG2` to do the replacement, then replace TAG1 and TAG2 with /* and */ again, but this is quite laborious and I would anyway like to know what is wrong with `/\**\*/`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly find comments starting with `/*` and ending with `*/`, you can use the following Word-style regex (with wildcard search enabled):

```
/\*?@\*/
```

As you have already discovered, `/\**\*/` for whatever reason does not work, and that’s because `*` is strange with spaces. Trying `/\**C` also does not yield any results even though it should work.

So instead of using `*`, we replace it with `?@`, “any character”, “one or more times”. This gives the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Also from the other answer /[*]*/ seems to work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/[*]*/` or `/[*A-Za-z0-9]*/` to find text between (and including) /* and */.
Another alternative is to use `/*/`, but it will also find texts that  are not comments (code separated by comments)

Make sure that for the Search options you select Use wildcards.